# Sending an email with a recurring calendar event doesn't always display correctly in email application

Tags: c#, email, icalendar

I'm trying to send an email with a recurring calendar event on our server. When the recipients receive the email and open it, I'd like it to appear as an invitation that they can accept (adding it to their calendar) or decline. Right now, the email that's sent is inconsistent based on the recurring info; sometimes, it appears as the invitation as I'd like. Other times, it's an email with headers that's base64 encoded

I created the appointment by creating a string that has the syntax of an .ics file, created an AlternateView from that string, and added that AlternateView to the email mailMessage:

```c#
mail.FromAddress = DoNotReplyAddress;
mail.ToAddress = emailRecipients;
mail.Subject = subject;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string DateFormat = "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ";
string now = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat);
sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
sb.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN");
sb.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
sb.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
DateTime dtStart = cronObject.StartDate;
DateTime dtEnd = cronObject.StartDate.AddHours(1);
sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
sb.AppendLine("DTSTART:" + dtStart.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat));
sb.AppendLine("DTEND:" + dtEnd.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat));
sb.AppendLine(repeatRule);
sb.AppendLine("DTSTAMP:" + now);
sb.AppendLine("UID:" + Guid.NewGuid());
sb.AppendLine(String.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", emailBody));
sb.AppendLine("CREATED:" + now);
sb.AppendLine("LAST-MODIFIED:" + now);
sb.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:0");
sb.AppendLine("STATUS:CONFIRMED");
sb.AppendLine(String.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", subject));
sb.AppendLine(String.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", "Direct Report 1", emailRecipients));
sb.AppendLine("TRANSP:OPAQUE");
sb.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
sb.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

ContentType calendarContentType = new ContentType("text/calendar");
calendarContentType.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
calendarContentType.Parameters.Add("name", "Meeting.ics");
Mail.AlternateView calendarView = Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(sb.ToString(), calendarContentType);
mail.mailMessage.Headers.Add("Content-class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
mail.Send(new List<Mail.AlternateView> { calendarView });
```

When `repeatRule = "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR"`, the email appears the way I want it to:[Correct email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v6m4.png)

But, if I change `repeatRule = "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO"` and keep everything else the same, the email looks like this:[Incorrect email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUIud.png)

If you base64 decode this email content, it will show the original .ics file string. Is this something I can fix or is it an issue with email applications misinterpreting the email content? I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. In section 3.8.5.3 of RFC 5545:

> The "DTSTART" property defines the first instance in the recurrence set.  The "DTSTART" property value SHOULD be synchronized with the recurrence rule, if specified.  The recurrence set generated with a "DTSTART" property value not synchronized with the recurrence rule is undefined.

The "DTSTART" property is a date that's the first occurrence of the calendar event. If there is also a "BYDAY" list included in the "RRULE" property, it should always contain the day of the week that "DTSTART" is on.